# Kubernetes ExternalName, exposing 10.0.2.2

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have created a mongo Service as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-svc
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.0.2.2
  ports:
  - port: 27017
```

When starting the cluster with the following command:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

I would expect the Virtualbox loopback address (10.0.2.2) to be mapped to the local Mongo DB instance that runs on my localhost machine.

However when logging in into a pod and trying to ping 10.0.2.2, I experience a 100% package loss.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are trying to expose MongoDB as an external service and basically map mongo-svc to 10.0.2.2, then

the first issue is that ExtrnalName must the fully qualified domain name of the actual service, as per Kubernetes doc:
“ExternalName accepts an IPv4 address string, but as a DNS name comprised of digits, not as an IP address. ExternalNames that resemble IPv4 addresses are not resolved by CoreDNS or ingress-nginx..”

The second issue is that the whole point of external service is to abstract external services by creating ExternalName service so that pods can connect to the external service through  mongo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local (use the default if your mongo-svc in a default namespace, which seems to be the case based on your YAML) and not use external service name and its location so that you can modify the service definition and point to another service if needed.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion as for how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: There is an open issue in Kubernetes Github: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2735. It is still an open issue but may lead you to a solution. There've been suggestions to develop new Minikube addon, so probably it'll be done in later releases. Also, you might take a look at this potential solution  [https://www.telepresence.io].

Comment: I switched to Docker For Mac and use `docker.for.mac.localhost`. It runs fine now. Perhaps I'll reconsider Minikube in the future.